# Access DB backup in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, ms-access-2010

Hello I am working on a Library system project in C# using Access and I need to make a backup of the current DB and do a restore.  My solution has multiple projects in it.  My DB is kept in a project called Library.Core. In this project it has a folder called Projects and in that folder another folder called Books.  The Books folder is where the Books_NE.mdb is located.  In my other project called Library.View I have a Controls folder and in that folder a Tabs folder that contains my different tabs such as my TransmitPanel.xaml  On my TransmitPanel.xaml I have added a button called Backup. Being that I am using Access I don’t need the extra steps has I would if using SQL.  I looked on the site and found the below solution and added it to my code.

[How to create a database backup on c#.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16515940/how-to-create-a-database-backup-on-c-net?rq=1)

File.Copy(sourceDbName, destDbName, true);

My Code for my Backup DB Button is as follows:

```
private void BackupDatabase_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            File.Copy(Books_NE.mdb, Books_NEBak.mdb, true);
        }
```

With the above code I receive the following two errors:

The name ‘Books_NE.mdb’ does not exist in the current context. The name ‘Books_NEbak.mdb’ does not exist in the current context.

My question is do I need to add something additional to my copy statement or should I use a different method?

Comment: You need to put quotes around the file names. File.Copy("Books_NE.mdb", "Books_NEBak.mdb", true);

Comment: Thank you dodald that definitely helped. Now I receive the error: Could not find the file Books_NE.mdb. Is this because I have it in another project within my solution? It's in the project called Books.Core => a folder called => Projects and in there a folder called Books which contains the DB. Does that mean I need to put the full path? Also This project will can be placed anywhere from desktop to c: drive depending on the person using it, so a constant path would not work. Would I use something like: File.Copy(@release\Projects\Library, "Books_NE.mdb", "Books_NEBak.mdb", true);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need quotes around strings

```
private void BackupDatabase_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            File.Copy("Books_NE.mdb", "Books_NEBak.mdb", true);
        }
```

Comment: Thank you Matt, that definitely helped.  Now I receive the error:  Could not find the file Books_NE.mdb.  Is this because I have it in another project within my solution? It's in the project called Books.Core => a folder called => Projects and in there a folder called Books which contains the DB. Does that mean I need to put the full path?  Also This project will can be placed anywhere from desktop to c: drive depending on the person using it, so a constant path would not work. Would I use something like: File.Copy(@release\Projects\Library, "Books_NE.mdb", "Books_NEBak.mdb", true);

Comment: So File.Copy will be inside whatever folder your executable is run from. You can give it relative paths such as "../../Projects/Library/Bookes_NE.mdb". This would tell the file system to go up 2 directory levels, then go in to Projects/Library and find the Books mdb file. Would something like that work for you?

Comment: The folder that contains the executable is called release. In that folder is a folder called Projects then the folder Library. I put the following code:   File.Copy("/release/Projects/Library/Books_NE.mdb", "Books_NEBak.mdb", true);   Even though that's where my DB is located I still receive the error could not find part of the path.

Comment: I was able to get it to do a backup but I had to put: File.Copy("c:/release/Projects/Library/Books_NE.mdb", Books_NEBal.mdb", true);    Being that the folder with the executable can be placed anywhere on someone's computer is there a way to do this where it does not need the entire path? Thanks for the help.

Comment: You can you relative paths to the file: "..\\Projects\\Library\\Books_NE.mdb" If you don't know exactly what to enter you should look up "relative paths" to learn how to make them work. (Basically each ..\\ goes up 1 folder from the current folder.)

Comment: If you have Projects/Library inside your release folder then you just need to use "Projects/Release/Books.mdb" to get to the file. Notice that you don't need to include "release" or the begining "/" in your path. File.Copy("Projects/Library/Books_NE.mdb"....)

Comment: I will read up on relative paths. Thank you dodald & Matt, it's working fine.